# Posting a File and it's Data (which can be an external file or a image) to a REST service in Json format

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I want to send a Json request body in postman, how do i send image and how do i associate/link a file which would could be sent through postman as a part of json request,i am able to send requests both post and get, but whenever i am trying to send a image file i am getting error in spring boot.

Comment: Can you please share the request you are trying to send and the response you are getting?

Comment: What's the error? Provide code/screen shot

Comment: @sofoGial : the request is :

{
 "Detail":
[
 {"Name":"Deborpita",
 "age":"25",
 "image":"00022B9A000000010001"
   
 }
 ]
 
}

Comment: I am trying to send the image as a byteArray but i am not  able to send it

Comment: Please share the source code if you have any.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you have code that doesn't work, your question should contain the code (all the code required to reproduce the problem), the errors that you get (stack traces - in text, formatted with the `{}` button) a description of what you expect and what you get instead. Please [edit] your question and improve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please read before you post next question !

Answer (score 1):

You might try converting the file into a base 64 string, then pass it to your JSON payload. This procedure is pretty common, and you are likely to find a library for it for your frontend code.

Since you are to deconstruct the file, make sure to add some of the image's useful metadata (which depends to the software you are making) in the payload, too.

Example:

```
{
    "name": "alice",
    "age": 20,
    "image": {
        "filename": "picture.png",
        "fileType": "image/png",
        "data": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
    }
}
```

A word of caution: Converting a file to base 64 is slow and will make its size larger, thus making the transfer via REST slower.